# Apply aggregate function based on column name in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table test3 which has the data below. I want to apply aggregate function based on status.

```
request mkt_val fill_val qty fill_qty rate c_party status
------- ------- -------- --- -------- ---- ------- ------
    IBM     200      100  20       10    1   test1 Accept
    IBM     300      200  30       20    2   test1 Accept
    IBM     400      300  40       30    3   test1 Accept
    IBM     500      400  50       40    4   test2 Reject
    IBM     600      500  60       50    5   test2 Reject
```

I need output with the columns:

- request
- a_sum_mkt_val
- a_avg_fill_qty
- a_min_rate
- r_sum_mkt_val
- r_avg_fill_qty
- r_min_rate
- c_cnt (distinct c_party for request)
- total_req (total number of records for request)

Prefix `a_` for accept, `r_` for reject. For the sample data, the output should be:

```
IBM  900  20  1  1100  45  4  2  5
```

I am not able to categorise the value based on the status.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: its a oracle database.oracle 10g database table test3

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could post some DDL for creating your table and inserting data into it.

Comment: What do you mean by a_sum_ and r_sum_?

Comment: INSERT INTO test3  VALUES('IBM',200,100,20,10,1,'test2','Reject');
INSERT INTO test3  VALUES('IBM',300,200,30,20,2,'test2','Reject');
INSERT INTO test3  VALUES('IBM',400,300,40,30,3,'test2','Reject');
INSERT INTO test3  VALUES('IBM',500,400,50,40,4,'test2','Reject');
insert into test3  values('IBM',600,500,60,50,5,'test2','Reject');


a_sum means sum FOR accept record
r_sum means sum for reject record


requets           a_sum_mkt_val      r_sum_mkt_val
IBM                 900                     1100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8319f0/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl ( request, mkt_val, fill_val, qty, fill_qty, rate,  c_party,  status ) AS
          SELECT 'IBM',     200,      100,  20,       10,    1,   'test1', 'Accept' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'IBM',     300,      200,  30,       20,    2,   'test1', 'Accept' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'IBM',     400,      300,  40,       30,    3,   'test1', 'Accept' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'IBM',     500,      400,  50,       40,    4,   'test2', 'Reject' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'IBM',     600,      500,  60,       50,    5,   'test2', 'Reject' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT request,
       SUM( DECODE( status, 'Accept', mkt_val,  NULL ) ) AS a_sum_mkt_val,
       AVG( DECODE( status, 'Accept', fill_qty, NULL ) ) AS a_avg_fill_qty,
       MIN( DECODE( status, 'Accept', rate,     NULL ) ) AS a_min_rate,
       SUM( DECODE( status, 'Reject', mkt_val,  NULL ) ) AS r_sum_mkt_val,
       AVG( DECODE( status, 'Reject', fill_qty, NULL ) ) AS r_avg_fill_qty,
       MIN( DECODE( status, 'Reject', rate,     NULL ) ) AS r_min_rate,
       COUNT( DISTINCT c_party ) AS c_cnt,
       COUNT( 1 ) AS total_req
FROM   tbl
GROUP BY request
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8319f0/3/0)**:

```
| REQUEST | A_SUM_MKT_VAL | A_AVG_FILL_QTY | A_MIN_RATE | R_SUM_MKT_VAL | R_AVG_FILL_QTY | R_MIN_RATE | C_CNT | TOTAL_REQ |
|---------|---------------|----------------|------------|---------------|----------------|------------|-------|-----------|
|     IBM |           900 |             20 |          1 |          1100 |             45 |          4 |     2 |         5 |
```

Comment: Good, but if you are happy with it then please accept the answer.